# Can't reset the secondary query by wp_reset_postdata()

Tags: wp-query, wp-reset-postdata

In custom post meta I have executed a custom query to get custom meta but when I tried to return to  the main $post query, its printing the secondary loop.Where is my custom query and I have reset it by wp_reset_postdata().But no result.

```
                            $custom_fields  = get_posts( array(    'post_type'      => 'custom_field',
                                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                                'meta_key'       => 'associate',
                                'meta_value'     => 'form'
                            ) );

                                foreach ($custom_fields as $post) {
                                    setup_postdata($post);
                                    var_dump(get_the_ID());
                                }
                                wp_reset_postdata();
                                wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_reset_query` is meant to be used with a loop, because it resets the global `$wp_query` object. `get_posts`, on the other hand, just returns an array to be iterated with ie. `foreach`. `setup_postdata` does **not** populate the `$wp_query` object: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata.

For a custom query, you would either use the `WP_Query` class, or you could reset your posts array using standard PHP functions like [reset](http://php.net/manual/de/function.reset.php).

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query